# Regex to extract each alphanumeric pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split, match

I have a string like following

`19990101 - John DoeLorem ipsum dolor sit amet 19990102 - Elton Johnconsectetur adipiscing elit`

How can I write a regex that would give me these two separate strings

`19990101 - John DoeLorem ipsum dolor sit amet`

`19990102 - Elton Johnconsectetur adipiscing elit`

The regex I wrote works up to this

`/\d+ -/gm`

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oin2F.png)

But I don't know how can I include the alphabets there as well

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ppzdk.png)

Comment: for the OP's string this one already should do it ... [`str.split(/(?<=\w)\s+(?=\d)/)`](https://regex101.com/r/5HKnQz/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
const text = '19990101 - John DoeLorem ipsum dolor sit amet 19990102 - Elton Johnconsectetur adipiscing elit';
console.log(text.match(/\d+\s+-[A-Za-z0-9\s]*[A-Za-z]/g))
console.log(text.split(/(?!^)\s+(?=\d+\s+-)/))
```

The `text.match(/\d+\s+-[A-Za-z0-9\s]*[A-Za-z]/g)` approach is *extracting* the alphanumeric/whitespace chars after `\d+\s+-` pattern. *Details*:

- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[A-Za-z0-9\s]*` - zero or more alphanumeric or whitespace chars
- `[A-Za-z]` - a letter

The `text.split(/(?!^)\s+(?=\d+\s+-)/)` splitting approach breaks the string with one or more whitespaces before one or more digits + one or more whitespaces + `-`:

- `(?!^)` - not at the start of string
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?=\d+\s+-)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with one or more digits + one or more whitespaces + `-`.

Answer (score 1):

For the OP's use case a regex based [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) like with ... [`str.split(/(?<=\w)\s+(?=\d)/)`](https://regex101.com/r/5HKnQz/1) ... already should do it.

The regex uses [lookarounds](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind), here trying to match any whitespace (sequence)/`\s+` which is both led/`(?<= ... )` by a word/`\w` and is followed/`(?= ... )` by a digit/`\d` character.

```js
console.log(
  '19990101 - John DoeLorem ipsum dolor sit amet 19990102 - Elton Johnconsectetur adipiscing elit 19990101 - John DoeLorem ipsum dolor sit amet 19990102 - Elton Johnconsectetur adipiscing elit'
    .split(/(?<=\w)\s+(?=\d)/)
);
```